# How do I place an icon inside another element?

Tags: html, css

I have this box:
[image: Box]
With this HTML:

```
<p class="box info"><span class="material-icons blue">record_voice_over</span>Sometimes minor spelling changes occur. For example, in Spanish we don't have "ss", so profe<strong>ss</strong>or becomes profe<strong>s</strong>or. Also, "th" in English becomes "t" in Spanish, as in au<strong>th</strong>or → au<strong>t</strong>or.</p>
```

And this CSS:

```
p.box.advice { 
    background: #ECFFE2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #008037;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

I'm trying to understand how to place the icon as part of the box, so it's responsive, like this:
[image: Box with centred icon]

From what I found, I think I need to create a new class, like `.icon-box`, and then in the HTML do something like:

```
<p class="box info"><i class="icon-box"><span class="material-icons blue">record_voice_over</span></i>Sometimes... </p>
```

But I don't know what properties I need to add to that class so the icon is responsive, and I don't really understand how the HTML would work there. I've read some MDN documentation about position and I think the `absolute` property, but as I'm completely new to these I don't even know the words to look for.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` for this.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #deeefe;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #004bad;
}

.box p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  flex: 1;
}

.box .material-icons {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box info"><i class="icon-box"><span class="material-icons blue">record_voice_over</span></i><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p></div>
```

Comment: For some reason you have an extra ```<p>```  tag (an empty one) in the box. Maybe it gets added if you create a line break you added to have additional space above the text, if this is the case, you can select the ```.box.info p``` and add ```margin-top``` to it instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing now in the console there's an extra <p> tag, there are no line breaks and removing the one I have doesn't help. I don't want any space above, the way it shows on Codepen is perfect, not sure what WordPress is doing there.

Comment: Try using a ```div``` element instead of ```p```, see what happens, you need to update the ```CSS``` as well.

Comment: Hmm...  If I remove the `<span class="material-icons blue">record_voice_over</span>` part, the text is properly displayed. What could that mean?

Comment: Lo siento, I don't know how that specific part of WP backend works... But it should though, it's not a complex formed piece of html.

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot, I appreciate your time. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

use flexbox: just wrap text inside .box in a div or a p tag. It will be responsive, no matter what

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ECFFE2;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.box span {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width:20%;
}
.box div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="box info">
  <span class="material-icons blue">record_voice_over</span> 
  <div>Sometimes...<div> 
</p>
```